# Multiple document gets deleted from firestore collection from the view while deleting one

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am subscribed to a collection using the async pipe, however when I go to delete a document inside the collection, any document below the deleted document also gets removed from the UX and but when i reload the component, i get that document again from firestore.

This is the code i am using to fetch guide collection

```
getGuides() {
return this.db.collection('guides').snapshotChanges()
  .map(data => {
    return data.map(a => {

      let id = a.payload.doc.id;
      let data = a.payload.doc.data();
      return { id, ...data };
    })
  })
}
```

And this code is to delete the document with it's id

```
deleteGuide(id) {
     return this.db.doc('guides/' + id).delete();
}
```

Thanks!

gif with problem

[image]

Comment: just to be sure, did you console log the id parameters used in deleteGuide ?

Comment: yes i did and it gave me the id of document which i just deleted